# Single website won't load on entire network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, website

This is a new problem. It occured suddenly and without change to any settings or me doing anything to my network connection.

Whenever I try to access quora.com, or any page on the site, whether it be on my Mac, Windows PC, iPhone, or Kindle, the site won't load. Every other website loads just fine on my network. When I attempt to access Quora on any other network with the same devices, it loads just fine.

Ping tests are unresponsive. What could the problem be? How can I fix it?

Comment: Ping is not a network test. It's it's own network protocol and is usually disabled. It is NEVER reliable. One day I hope the "ping is a network test" myth dies.

Comment: It is actually very simple: since the site is up and running (I just checked), it means that, for some reason they have blocked your IP.  In this case, the only thing you can do is talk to them. As for ping, it replies to my pings, hence, *a fortiori*, they blocked your IP.

Comment: Ah c'mon @MariusMatutiae, there are lots of other reasons why a site won't load besides "they blocked your IP".

Comment: @Spiff Sure, yet... let's see a traceroute to the site. Please use *mtr*, a very convenient utility which exists for all OSes. It will readily identify bottlenecks on the way, including giving hints on the existence of firewalls.

Comment: Seems to me that your ISP has blocked Quora, probably by mistake. If it happened suddenly and without any change on your side it's the only logical explanation.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae `mtr` does not exist on windows. `pathping` does and as far as I can see does pretty much the same as `mtr`

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes it does exist: it is just called WinMTR instead of simply mtr, that's all. http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmtr/